# Compare each date range of 1st table with all the rows of the date range second table to get the non overlapping date range from 1st table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0dAB.png]

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mnel.png)]

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nDVq.png)]

I have tried joins and all but it is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post a complete working example, including sample data. Show what you tried - "I tried joins" - what does that mean ? We cannot see what you tried. Don't paste images, but post text.

Answer (score 0):

`UNPIVOT` the dates and then you can use analytic functions to find the bounds of each part of the time series and use the difference between the numbers of starts and ends for each table to calculate the overlaps (and non-overlaps):

```sql
SELECT st, ed
FROM   (
SELECT dt as st,
       LEAD(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) - CASE LEAD(type) OVER (ORDER BY dt) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN table_type = 1 THEN type ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS num_range1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN table_type = 2 THEN type ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS num_range2
FROM   (
  SELECT dt, type, 1 AS table_type
  FROM   table1
  UNPIVOT (dt FOR type IN (st1 AS 1, ed1 As -1))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dt, type, 2
  FROM   table2
  UNPIVOT (dt FOR type IN (st2 AS 1, ed2 As -1))
  ORDER BY dt
)
)
WHERE  num_range1 > 0
AND    num_range2 = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (st1, ed1) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-06-05', DATE '2020-08-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-09-01', DATE '2020-09-15' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (st2, ed2) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-05-01', DATE '2020-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-07-01', DATE '2020-07-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-08-01', DATE '2020-08-13' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ST | ED |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-10 00:00:00 | 2020-06-30 00:00:00 |
| 2020-07-03 00:00:00 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 2020-08-13 00:00:00 | 2020-08-15 00:00:00 |
| 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 2020-09-15 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zerg6HAt)